# Why is Gary Unwin's nickname "Eggsy"?

Tags: kingsman-the-secret-service

I watched the movie *Kingsman: The Secret Service* and the main character's nickname isn't explained anywhere. What does "Eggsy" mean? Did he get it for cooking very good breakfast sunny side up? Google and Wikipedia didn't help with the answer.

Comment: i've always thought it was a reference to the nursery rhyme "Humpty Dumpty", especially the line " all the Kings horses and all the King's men". "King's men"? sounds a lot like kingsmen to me! Humpty Dumpty was an egg, hence 'Eggsy'.

Comment: I thought it maybe had to do with the fact that the actor who plays "Eggsy"s name is "Taron Egerton".

Answer (score 15):

According to [Mark Millar -- the author of the comic book -- in an interview with Comic Book Resources](http://www.comicbookresources.com/?page=article&id=50173):

> *And on the "changes over time" front, I understand that "The Secret
> Service" will make a slight change to Jack's name. What precipitated
> this? Did "Jack London" just feel the call of the wild?*
>
> Funny you should say that because, as a kid, I just thought that was a
> cool name and I wrote it into the book because I liked it. But Matthew
> said legally we couldn't call him that in the movie any more than we
> could call him Tom Clancy. So we bounced a lot of names around and,
> since I named Gary after one of my friends, he renamed Jack after his
> oldest school-friend. **In the original draft of the comic I gave Gary
> my friend's old nickname of "Eggsy" because I thought it was funny,
> but thought everybody would hate it. But Matthew and Jane loved it and
> used that as Gary's nickname in the movie so I've worked it back into
> a couple of panels in the book. I kind of love the madness of a
> superspy called Eggsy. Matthew thought it was really iconic and since
> I named this after one of my pals he felt it was only fair to call the
> other after one of his.**

---

He [said the same thing on Twitter](https://twitter.com/mrmarkmillar/status/357590339072180224) on 17 July 2013:

> **I gave Gary the nickname EGGSY in Secret Service after a school pal**,
> but thought it was too mad. Now it's in script. Pal will be
> chuffed!

And followed this up with [this tweet](https://twitter.com/mrmarkmillar/status/357591324221911040):

> Anyway, the St Ambrose Eggsy has now been immortalised as it's Gary's nickname in the Secret Service movie.

---

[Millar offers this explanation](http://www.denofgeek.com/movies/mark-millar/33787/mark-millar-interview-kingsman-foxs-marvel-films) for the nickname in an interview with Den of Geek:

> **Den of Geek:** Director Matthew Vaughn used both the phrase “good egg” and “bad egg”
> in talking about the characters in this film. It dawned on me that the
> lead character being called Eggsy might not be an accident.
>
> **Mark Millar:** It’s my old school friend’s name. One of my three best friends that I
> used to hang around with, and **the reason he was called Eggsy** - and he
> wasn’t a tough guy or anything like the character in the film - **is
> just that he didn’t like eggs.** We were all about fourteen and having
> dinner at somebody’s house and there was an egg in the meal and he
> said “Oh, I don’t eat them.” I said “Who doesn’t like eggs?” “I’ve
> never tasted one.” “You must have! Are you kidding me?”
>
> I dedicated the book to him.

---

There is also the explanation offered at [this Q&A](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/User_blog:MrBlonde267/Kingsman_Fan_Q%26A:_Mark_Millar_and_Dave_Gibbons):

> MARVEL DATABASE: Do you know where the nickname "Eggsy" came from? It wasn't in the comics but perhaps you had a chat with Matthew Vaughn which triggered the change. I've been trying to figure some theories about it myself but have had no luck. Eggsy had that nickname since he was a kid (Scene in movie). Seriously curious about this one. Thank you so much! - Ariana Castellano
>
> MARK MILLAR: **Gary Unwin was called Eggsy after one of my old school-friends.** I had written this into the comic originally and took it out because I thought the name might be a bit silly. But Matthew loved it and shoved it into the movie and I agreed and put it back in the comic. The real Eggsy is delighted of course and when I took him to the premiere having his name said every 10 seconds really made the movie for him. **We called him Eggsy at school because he stunned us all when we were fourteen by saying he’d never eaten an egg.** His reasoning was good enough. It does sound vaguely disgusting when you think about it.

Comment: This is certainly correct... But I was sort of hoping for an etymological explanation for where the name came from (in story) in the first place... And I sort of think that's what the question is looking for, too.

Comment: @Catija Millar's answer makes it clear there is no explanation.

Comment: Perhaps I'm dense but surely there's some sort of explanation... Even if it's not in-story... Like how his friend got the name or is it common in the UK...

Comment: @Catija I've found another interview in which he explains the nickname.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very popular band goldie lookin chain one of the band members is called eggsy. The way Gary dresses is very similar to the way eggsy dresses gold chain around neck,rapper hat,and a pull over. Hence it might be a reference to that.

Answer (score 0):

I am not from UK one and English is not my mother tongue, so sorry for my ridiculous answer. When Charley mock of his name he say it as "eggy" for me it is small egg. After it Arthur mock about it when he say that Roxy have "the eggs" unlike you Eggsy. So, i think Eggsy it's the kind of slang -brave boy, the one with the eggs.  Sorry for my ridiculous assumption.

Answer (score -1):

When he is a child, after his dad dies Harry asks him what his name is. He answers Eggsy, that's when Harry gives him the medal with the phone number on the back. So has nothing to do with when he's older, or a nickname etc. it's his birth name and shown at the very beginning.

Comment: Starting at 16:30, when Eggsy calls the number on the medallion, he says _"My name's Eggsy Unwin - sorry, Gary Unwin [...]"_ so definitely a nickname.